# Problem with Dependent pattern matching in COQ

Tags: coq

(small update to make it closer to my real task)

How to write `f2` using dependent pattern matching? (Code below compiles except definition of `f2`)

```
Inductive parse_ret : Set :=
  No : parse_ret | Yes : parse_ret.

Inductive exp : parse_ret -> Set :=
| No_parse : exp No
| Yes_parse : exp Yes.

Definition f1 (p : parse_ret) : option (exp p) :=
  match p with
  | No => Some No_parse
  | Yes => Some Yes_parse
  end.
          
Definition f2' : option nat :=
  match f1 No with
  | Some No_parse => Some 1
  | Some Yes_parse => Some 1
  | None => None
  end.
```

So, f2' is almost what I need, but `Some Yes_parse` is obviously redundant here because we provided `No` constructor to `f1` and `f1`'s return type becomes `option (exp No)`.

How to write definition for `f2`? avoiding the `Non exhaustive pattern-matching` error?

```
Definition f2 : option nat :=
  match f1 No with
  | Some No_parse => Some 1
  | None => None                            
  end.
```

Comment: May I ask where that example comes from? I’ve been working a bit on the elaboration of pattern-matching, and we’re looking for examples of the kind of issues users face with the current one as test-cases.

Comment: I am working as proof engineer at https://formal.land/ we verify source code of https://tezos.com/. Tezos is having code written in OCaml. We converted OCaml code into Coq with Coq-of-oCaml (https://formal.land/docs/coq-of-ocaml/introduction) and prove it's correctness. My example is simplified version of problem I faced during job. Kind of real-life problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, I believe, a defect of the pattern-matching compilation algorithm of Coq. This is the part that is responsible of elaborating a fancy pattern-matching you write as a user into one comprehensible by the kernel.

Here, it has to do two things: one is to desugar a deep pattern-matching (matching over `option` and `exp` at once) into two nested pattern-matching; the other is to detect that some constructors are not to be considered because of the typing constraint, which would allow you to avoid giving the `Some Yes_parse` clause. However, the algorithm is not able to do this in its current state.

Thus, you have to help it by hand. One possibility is to do part one for it, and write

```
Definition f2' : option nat :=
  match f1 No with
    | None => None
    | Some p =>
      match p in exp r with
        | No_parse => Some 1
      end
  end.
```

Coq is happy with this, and if you print the elaborated term you get

```
match f1 No with
| Some p =>
    match p in (exp r) return match r with
                              | No => option nat
                              | Yes => IDProp
                              end with
    | No_parse => Some 1
    | Yes_parse => idProp
    end
| None => None
end
```

where you see that the elaborator has massaged the inner match and introduced a smart return clause to handle the non-exhaustiveness issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very familiar with fancy `match` expressions, but, in this very specific case, it seems it would be easier to just use `Some _` in the match. You could prove, if you need this, a lemma stating that `f1 No` is always `Some No_parse`.

You could also instead define `f2` to take an argument of type `option (exp No)`, and delegate the issue to the function caller.

Of course, all this may be stating the obvious...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, this is what I had to do... but still interested how to use fancy match expression in my case.